# geting system failure messages after bootup

Tags: gnome-shell, crash, system

I get the system error popup at seemingly random times, including after bootup if I leave the computer idle for a few minutes.

It always seems to be the same deal, something like the following:

```
-rw-r----- 1 gdm whoopsie 32585348 Feb 19 09:41 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.121.crash
```

I know I can just disable apport, but does anyone recognize what this error is exactly? I'd prefer to deal with it if at all possible.

Comment: Read the crash file in /var/crash

Comment: I reported what /var/crash said in my post.

Comment: /var/crash is a directory. You simply showed us a file name. You must actually open and read the file.